# Django settings.py import error in mange.py Configuration error

Tags: django, heroku, django-forms, django-rest-framework, heroku-api

Thanks in Advance for My Query.

I have created a django project which has manage.py file inside src folder it works fine when running terminal from SRC folder.

FOr Heroku deployement manage.py should be placed in root directory so i updated manage.py file with  "os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "**src.tweetme.settings**")"

Changed "os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "**tweetme.settings**")" to "os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "**src.tweetme.settings**")"  import issue is faced on running locally. Need solution how to import setting.py inside two folder deep.

```html
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "src.tweetme.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError:
        # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
        # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
        # exceptions on Python 2.
        try:
            import django
        except ImportError:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            )
        raise
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

***I am facing following Error:*** attached Error_Message.png

**Hiras-Mac-mini-2:tweethere apple$ python manage.py runserver**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 23, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 307, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 56, in **getattr**
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 110, in **init**
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in import_module
    **import**(name)
**ImportError: No module named src.tweetme.settings**

***This Is my Package Structure:***attached Project_Structure.png

```
-Project
    -bin
    -include
    -lib
    -src
       -subProject1
       -subProject2
       -subProject3
       -mainProject
             -Settings
                 -__init__.py
                 -base.py
                 -local.py
                 -production.py
       -manage.py
       -db.sqlite3
    -static-serve
       -.env
       -.python
       -manage.py
       -ProcFile
      -requirements.txt
```

[Project_Structure.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmjTc.png)[Error_Message.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfM6g.png)

Comment: Your question is confusing because you use a mixture of real directory names like `tweethere` and made-up names like `mainProject`. It would be much clearer if you used the real name everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If `manage.py` is not in the `src` directory, then you need to add `src` to the Python path.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('src')
```

You should then keep `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` as it was, without `src`.

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "tweetme.settings")
```